# display name from local Storage to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want my html page will display "WELCOME" and the user name from local storage.
I have the name in local storage but I don't know how to display it in HTML page

js file:

```
//register
function store(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var pw = document.getElementById('pw').value;
    ...
    const user = { name: name, pw: pw};
    const userObjectString = JSON.stringify(user);
    localStorage.setItem(name, userObjectString);
    window.location = "./user.html";
    alert('Your account has been created');
  }
 //login
 function check(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
        var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw').value;
        var userObjectString = window.localStorage.getItem(userName);
        if (!userObjectString && userName != "gk" && userPw != "123") {
            alert('Error on login');
        } else {
            var user = JSON.parse(userObjectString);
            if(userName == user.name && userPw == user.pw){
                alert('You are logged in.');
                window.location = "./user.html";
            } else {
                alert('Error on login');
            }
         }
       }
```

Comment: FYI - Please do not do authentication like this. You need a proper authentication service (no in the client so it can't be bypassed trivially) that would normally provide you with user info like username.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+localStorage+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes in the localStorage key AND use textContent to stop possibly XSS:

```
localStorage.setItem("name", userObjectString);
```

then you can do

```
const obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name") || \`{}\`);
if (obj && obj.name) document.querySelector("h1").textContent += obj.name;
```

assuming you have

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Note you may want to sanitize the name before saving it

Comment: This is wrong; `obj.name` should be HTML-encoded before feeding it into `innerHTML`. Right now, it is putting the door ajar for XSS attacks.

Comment: How? The name comes from the same page by the same user. If the computer is public then maybe yes, but then there are more problems with the code than XSS from localStorage

Comment: First of all, SO is a source of knowledge, making your code eventually find its way towards complex multi-user systems. The code makes a _very_ bad example for others to follow. Secondly, single-user applications are still vulnerable for social engineering attacks. _Never_ assume the contents of user input or data storage will be sane; some people blindly copy/paste whatever they are told to.

Comment: Third, combine this code with a zero-day exploit in a web browser (giving a hacker access to local storage), and there's your hack. Little vulnerabilities are worth gold for hackers, because unlike what you see in the movies, modern hacking attempts do not exploit one big vulnerability; they combine many small vulnerabilities. Give them a finger and they'll take your hand.

Comment: OP is storing userid and password in plain text in his web page. I think OP's target audience is not the global community. I will make a note of your comments -  I have changed to textContent from innerHTML